# SYNTAX error in mysql version 5.5

Tags: mysql

Hi looking to run a SQL but getting a syntax error which I am unsure off I have copied mysql in below:

Hi looking to run a SQL but getting a syntax error which I am unsure off I have copied mysql in below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CUSTOMER`; 
CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMER` (   
`ACCT_ID` INT NOT NULL  , 
`FIRST_NAME` VARCHAR(10) , 
`LAST_NAME` VARCHAR(9) , 
`ADDRESS_1` VARCHAR(34) , 
`ADDRESS_2` VARCHAR(7) , 
`ADDRESS_3` VARCHAR(8) , 
`ADDRESS_4` VARCHAR(7) , 
`CONTACT` VARCHAR(14) , 
`EMAIL` VARCHAR(47) , 
`REG_DATE` DATETIME , 
`LAST_PURCHASE` DATETIME , 
PRIMARY KEY  (`ACCT_ID`) );
```

-- -- Dumping data for table `CUSTOMER` --

```
    INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER`  VALUES  
    (97675789,'Samantha','Jones','8837 Pellentesque Ave','Dublin','Leinster','Ireland',NULL,'nec@fringillaDonecfeugiat.ca','2015-03-13 00:00:00','2015-11-04 00:00:00'); 
(93872909,'Vielka','Mitchell','P.O. Box 608, 5827 Dignissim St.','Galway','Connacht','Ireland','0855511623','Sed.nec@magnaPraesentinterdum.net','2015-03-26 00:00:00','2015-04-04 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you add multiple row in a single `insert` statement you separate them with `,` not `;`

So it would be as

```
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER`  
VALUES  
(97675789,'Samantha','Jones','8837 Pellentesque Ave','Dublin','Leinster','Ireland',NULL,
'nec@fringillaDonecfeugiat.ca','2015-03-13 00:00:00',
'2015-11-04 00:00:00'), -- should be , not ;
(93872909,'Vielka','Mitchell','P.O. Box 608, 
5827 Dignissim St.','Galway','Connacht','Ireland','0855511623',
'Sed.nec@magnaPraesentinterdum.net','2015-03-26 00:00:00',
'2015-04-04 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Abhik my database has been created now.